# How do I get the content with libxml2?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 and C++. The following function crashes here at `return (char*)cur->content;`. When I change it to `return (char*)cur->name;` then it will return `attribute` which is the name of the tag. What I want is 1, 2, and 3 (based on the XML file below the C++ code). What am I doing wrong?

```
char* xml2sdf::getId(xmlNode* part){

    xmlNode* cur = part->xmlChildrenNode;

    // get the id
    while (cur != NULL) {

        if ( !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"attribute") ) {
            xmlAttrPtr attr = cur->properties;

            if( !xmlStrcmp( attr->children->content, (const xmlChar*)"id" ) ){
                return (char*)cur->content;
            }
        }

        cur = cur->next;
        }

    }
}
```

The part of the XML file it is parsing:

```
<part ref="part10" name="part10">
    <attribute name="face">7</attribute>
    <attribute name="id">1</attribute>
</part>

<part ref="part20" name="part20">
    <attribute name="face">5</attribute>
    <attribute name="id">2</attribute>
</part>

<part ref="part30" name="part30">
    <attribute name="face">9</attribute>
    <attribute name="id">3</attribute>
</part>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered it should be `return (char*)cur->children->content;` by trial and error.

Comment: The content of a node is a child of that node, that is why you have to access children first. You might also consider using the xmlNodeGetContent function instead of directly accessing the structure. That is, "return (char*)xmlNodeGetContent( cur->children );".

Comment: Another option is the use of `(char*)XML_GET_CONTENT(cur->children)` macro, that puts an additional check for null pointers.